# Lagrange’s equation: from energies to Lagrangian form

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy

I don't understand how we step from
$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot q_j} - \frac{\partial T}{\partial q_j} = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial q_j}$$
to
$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q_j} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial q_j} = 0.$$

So, we have that $L = T-V.$ Therefore $\frac{\partial T}{\partial q_j} - \frac{\partial V}{\partial q_j} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial q_j}.$ But what about first term?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Lagrangian mechanics one assumed the potential to have no dependence on the variables $\dot q$, therefore
$$\frac{\text d}{\text dt}\frac{\partial T}{\partial\dot q}=\frac{\text d}{\text dt}\left[\frac{\partial T}{\partial\dot q} - \frac{\partial V}{\partial\dot q}\right] = \frac{\text d}{\text dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot q}$$
since the extra term is zero.